# Why is my joins/where lookup failing when I pass a variable into it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Models:

```
# committee.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :chambers

# chamber.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :committees
```

I'm trying to perform the following lookup (in a rake task, if that matters):

```
lookup = Committee.joins(:chambers)
           .where(chambers: { id: chamber.id })
           .where(name: clean_name)
           .first
```

The problem I'm having is with `clean_name` at the end. When I manually put `name: "Judiciary"` there the lookup succeeds as-expected. However, when "Judiciary" is passed into `clean_name` the lookup returns `nil`. I have tried `name: "#{clean_name}"` as well, but to no avail.

Here's how `clean_name` gets generated:

```
# scheduler.rake
# "committee" is previously-defined via an API lookup
clean_name = Committee.gsub_name(committee)

# committee.rb
# I have to sanitize the API-returned name in order to make
  it consistent with my own naming convention
def self.gsub_name(name)
  return name.gsub("Committee on the ", "").gsub("Committee on ", "").gsub("&#39;", "'").gsub("House ", "").gsub("Senate ", "").gsub("Committee", "")
end
```

I've confirmed that `gsub_name` returns the appropriate text before executing the lookup.

Here's the whole function in `scheduler.rake`:

```
def add_committee_for(bill, chamber)
  params = [
    :level => "#{chamber.government.level}",
    :endpoint => "bill_committee",
    :api_url => bill.api_url
  ]

  # Retrieve original unsuanitized value from API:
  committee = Bill.set_request(params)

  clean_name = Committee.gsub_name(committee)
  chamber_committees = chamber.committees
  yn_committee = Committee
    .joins(:chambers)
    .where(chambers: { id: chamber.id })
    .where(name: "#{clean_name.to_s}")
    .first
end
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in the string? You can call `clean_name.strip` to check that, it will eliminate whitespace.

Comment: @Iceman I thought I had solved for that with my gsubs but.... you nailed it. I'll accept your Answer soon as you post it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solved in the comments it turned out to be because of whitespace in the string. The solution is to use the [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip) method to get rid of that.

```
lookup = Committee.joins(:chambers)
       .where(chambers: { id: chamber.id })
       .where(name: clean_name.strip)
       .first
```